# angular.js form validation in controller

Tags: angularjs

I got this form:

```
<form ng-controller="SomeCtrl as some" name="product[[product.id]]" ng-submit="some.addToCart(something, product[[product.id]].$valid)" novalidate></form>
```

Then html looks like:

```
<form ng-controller="SomeCtrl as some" name="product1" ng-submit="some.addToCart(something, product1.$valid)" novalidate=""></form>
```

Controller:

```
this.addToCart = function(something, isValid) {
    console.log(isValid);
}
```

isValid is always `undefined`. How to detect if form is valid in controller?

Comment: Nope, in that example it's disabling submit button, but I don't want to do that, I want to check in controller $valid status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tBs073pIoYVfwBtW2gSQ?p=preview)
You don't want to use ng-submit if you want to do your own validation in the controller because it will block the submission of the form if it is invalid.

Just use a regular button with a function in ng-click that checks the condition of the form.

Controller:

```
  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.myForm.$valid)
  }
```

HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="myForm.text" type="text" required />
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```